# How to change the tab size in Android development in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

The default tab size in its editor is 4.
In windows->preference->general->text editors, I set 'displayed tab width' to be 2.
In windows->preference->android->editors, I checked 'use eclipse setting for indentation width and space or tab char...'
and also restarted the IDE. Its width is still 4.
How could I change it to be 2?

Comment: The width in the preference page or in the editor is still 4?

Comment: In the preference page, it is 2. But in my editor, if I type tab, it gives me 4 spaces still.

Comment: Literally 4 spaces, or moving you 4 columns over? You can use the arrow keys to tell whether you have a single tab occupying 4 columns or 4 space characters.

Comment: It is a single tab occupying 4 columns. Can we change it to be a single tab occupying only 2 columns?

Comment: You seem to be doing everything you should.  When you open a .txt file in the Eclipse Text Editor, do keying in a tab behave as it should?

Comment: Yes. A tab in txt file takes 2 columns. So, this means adt does not work well?

Comment: That it may be a bug specifically in the way they're handling it, yes.

Comment: I have the same issue, plus they don't allow me to replace tabs by spaces, even when I have marked the box saying so. It seems to be a bug from Eclipse with the Android plugin. The settings work for normal Java, though.